# COUNT is outputting more than one row

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am having a problem with my SQL query using the count function.

When I don't have an inner join, it counts 55 rows. When I add the inner join into my query, it adds a lot to it. It suddenly became 102 rows.

Here is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT COUNT([fmsStage].[dbo].[File].[FILENUMBER])
FROM [fmsStage].[dbo].[File]
INNER JOIN [fmsStage].[dbo].[Container]
    ON [fmsStage].[dbo].[File].[FILENUMBER] = [fmsStage].[dbo].[Container].[FILENUMBER]
WHERE [fmsStage].[dbo].[File].[RELATIONCODE] = 'SHIP02'
  AND [fmsStage].[dbo].[Container].DELIVERYDATE BETWEEN '2016-10-06' AND '2016-10-08'
GROUP BY [fmsStage].[dbo].[File].[FILENUMBER]
```

Also, I have to do `TOP 1` at the `SELECT` statement because it returns 51 rows with random numbers inside of them. (They are probably not random, but I can't figure out what they are.)

What do I have to do to make it just count the rows from `[fmsStage].[dbo].[file].[FILENUMBER]`?

Comment: What is confusing?  That is how `join` works between two tables.

Comment: You do GROUP BY. Expect one row/count per [fmsStage].[dbo].[File].[FILENUMBER] value.

Comment: I now removed the group by. But it outputs a number higher than before i added the inner join. Even though I am counting the row FILENUMBER from table FILE and not from the table CONTAINER. so why does it add up to it?

Comment: You are getting a count for each [FILENUMBER]  the the group by.    Do a select * without the group by and you should see what it going on.   There are some duplicate [FILENUMBER] in Container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your query would be much clearer like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(f.[FILENUMBER])
FROM [fmsStage].[dbo].[File] f INNER JOIN
     [fmsStage].[dbo].[Container] c
    ON v.[FILENUMBER] = c.[FILENUMBER]
WHERE f.[RELATIONCODE] = 'SHIP02' AND
      c.DELIVERYDATE BETWEEN '2016-10-06' AND '2016-10-08';
```

No `GROUP BY` is necessary.  Otherwise you'll just one row per file number, which doesn't seem as useful as the overall count.

Note:  You might want `COUNT(DISTINCT f.[FILENUMBER])`.  Your question doesn't provide enough information to make a judgement.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove GROUP BY Clause

```
SELECT COUNT([fmsStage].[dbo].[File].[FILENUMBER])
FROM [fmsStage].[dbo].[File]
INNER JOIN [fmsStage].[dbo].[Container]
    ON [fmsStage].[dbo].[File].[FILENUMBER] = [fmsStage].[dbo].[Container].[FILENUMBER]
WHERE [fmsStage].[dbo].[File].[RELATIONCODE] = 'SHIP02'
  AND [fmsStage].[dbo].[Container].DELIVERYDATE BETWEEN '2016-10-06' AND '2016-10-08'
```